# Problem on React, onClick take the last var and note the choosen one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const CharacterList = () => {



    const [change, setChange] = React.useState(false);

    const QuickSilver= () => setChange(!change);
    const SuperMan= () => setChange(!change);





return (
    <div id="character" className="list">
        
        <img id="icons" className="one" src={QuickSilverIc} onClick={QuickSilver} />
            {change && (
                <img className="card" src={QuickSilverStat} />
            )}
        <img id="icons" className="two" src={SuperManIc}  onClick={SuperMan} />
            {change && (
                <img className="card" src={SuperManStat} />
            )}
```

So, when i click on the QuickSilver img that bring me the img with src={SuperManStat} and not {QuickSilverStat}
If anyone can help me it will be very nice !
ps: yeah i've cut the react components to show you only what i want ofc ive done averything correctly, like import export etc...

Comment: With your current conditions you would either have `QuickSilverStat` and `SuperManStat` both or none

Comment: what are you tying todo?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to show only one of them. To achieve this, you should wrap both images of each one together, and show only one of them on each change value (true or false):

```
{change && (
    <div>
      <img id="icons" className="one" src={QuickSilverIc} onClick={QuickSilver} />
      <img className="card" src={QuickSilverStat} />
    </div>
)}
{!change && (
    <div>
      <img id="icons" className="two" src={SuperManIc}  onClick={SuperMan} />
      <img className="card" src={SuperManStat} />
    </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is create to different `useStates`  one for quicksilver and the other one for superman, or create an object with this shape

```js
const [hero, SetHero] = useState({superman: false, quicksilver:false});
```

and then in your onClickhandler you can pass the name and update the state to right hero

Answer (score 0):

```
{change ? (
  <>
    <img id="icons" className="one" src={QuickSilverIc} onClick={QuickSilver} />
    <img className="card" src={QuickSilverStat} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <img id="icons" className="two" src={SuperManIc}  onClick={SuperMan} />
    <img className="card" src={SuperManStat} />
  </>
)}
```